# Steps to build Perl 5.6.2 in Cygwin 1.7.11

Tags: perl, cygwin

I cannot seem to build perl 5.6.2 in Cygwin 1.7.11.

Here are the steps I am following to do it so far.

Download perl 5.6.2 source from website and untar to some folder "perl-5.6.2"

```
cd perl-5.6.2/bld
sh ../Configure -des -Dmksymlinks -Dprefix=/common/ndd/perl/5.6.2 -DDEBUGGING 2>&1
make 2>&1
make install 2>&1
```

Here are the logs from this:

http://pastebin.com/pqLg4S7z

What happens is make creates "perl-5.6.2/bld/perl.exe" and this file generates an abort signal every time.

Here is the backtrace from running gdb on it. (Note: I configured with -DDEBUGGING so all the gcc debug flags should be enabled.)

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /openlogic/build/work/perl-5.6.2/bld/perl.exe
[New Thread 3348.0xf54]
[New Thread 3348.0x48c]

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x7792f8b1 in ntdll!RtlUpdateClonedSRWLock ()
   from /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/ntdll.dll
#2  0x757f0a91 in WaitForSingleObjectEx ()
   from /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/KERNELBASE.dll
#3  0x000000a8 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) quit
```

Here id the ldd.exe command ran on perl.exe

```
$ ldd /ndipiazza/build/work/perl-5.6.2/bld/perl.exe
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SysWOW64/ntdll.dll (0x77910000)
        kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/kernel32.dll (0x75cb0000)
        KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/KERNELBASE.dll (0x757e0000)
        libperl5_6_2.dll => /ndipiazza/build/work/perl-5.6.2/bld/libperl5_6_2.dll (0x66140000)
        cygcrypt-0.dll => /usr/bin/cygcrypt-0.dll (0x67db0000)
        cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x61000000)
        ??? => ??? (0x570000)
```

Can anyone see why I would be getting this sigabrt?

EDIT: here is a link to a discussion going on in Cygwin mailing list: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-07/msg00368.html

Comment: Why would you want to install a version of Perl that is so old an completely unsupported? I bet you'd have far more success if you installed something recent.

Comment: Many instances of perl 5.6 still exist in the wild, and you might be surprised (or you might not be) how risk averse some organizations are about upgrading something that has "worked just fine" for many years. There are many trade-offs to consider, but developers who make their libraries compatible with older versions of Perl are performing a valuable service.

Comment: @mob OTOH, Cygwin comes with a version of `perl` that is somewhat more recent. I think it would be worth a shot to at least see how well that works.

Comment: Does it have to be a cygwin build? You could locate a 5.6 ActivePerl installer -- I might have one at home -- and MS's free compiler.

Comment: I may be projecting my own experiences onto this question, but I believe the OP is trying to install v5.6.2 *in addition to* one or more modern versions of perl already on his system. (for one thing, the OP is running `configure` with `-Dprefix=...` to install this perl to a custom directory)

Comment: Mob is correct. This is a must-have situation where there will indeed be more than 1 perl installation runnable at any given point. -Dprefix=/common/ndipiazza/perl/VERSION/
As much as I'd love to ditch perl 5.6.2, I cannot.

Comment: ActivePerl supports installation into any directory. Again, have you considered ActivePerl?

Comment: It is not open source. So it is not an option, unless I am mistaken?

Comment: Sometimes a client ( as mob says ) wants something and it doesn't matter how old or insecure it is.  That would be the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Perl 5.6.2 tries to use it's own malloc. This is incompatible with Cygwin's malloc.

I was given some help on Cygwin mailing list to fix this: http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-07/msg00380.html

Bottom line, add `-Dusemymalloc=n` to the sh ./Configure arguments.

Then it works.

Answer (score 5):

5.6 is outdated for your build environment. [Maintenance patches](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/tree/maint-5.6) exist.

I recommend to [install perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl) and [patchperl](http://p3rl.org/patchperl):

```
$ perlbrew install-patchperl
```

which will DTRT.

Comment: When I ran it on perl 5.6.2 it only changed one file. and that change didn't fix my problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm using it wrong? Can you try it on perl 5.6.2 to see if you get different results?

Comment: I don't have Cygwin, sorry. You can still try [rurban](http://stackoverflow.com/users/414279/rurban)'s [perlall](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlall). He is a Cygwin contributor and might give you assistance.

Comment: I will try to get a hold of him. do you know the best way?

Comment: I ran the perlall tool and was able to build and get to the exact same core dump from sigabort that I hit from the manual installer. This sounds like some sort of hard-set library conflict with perl5.6.2's dependencies and cygwin 1.7.11's normal runtime

Answer (score 4):

This question is above my pay grade and this is a shot in the dark, but the two things I remember that ruin a perl5.6.2 build on Cygwin are

1. spaces in the `$PATH` (e.g. `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/BlahBlahBlah`)
2. configure script unable to determine the signal names

Check your `config.sh` script and see whether it contains lines like

```
sig_count='1'
sig_name='ZERO '
sig_name_init='"ZERO", 0'
sig_num='0 '
sig_num_init='0, 0'
```

You want it to say something like

```
sig_count='33'
sig_name='ZERO HUP INT QUIT ILL TRAP ABRT EMT FPE KILL BUS SEGV SYS PIPE ALRM TERM URG STOP TSTP CONT CHLD TTIN TTOU IO XCPU XFSZ VTALRM PROF WINCH LOST USR1 USR2 RTMAX CLD POLL PWR RTMIN '
sig_name_init='"ZERO", "HUP", "INT", "QUIT", "ILL", "TRAP", "ABRT", "EMT", "FPE", "KILL", "BUS", "SEGV", "SYS", "PIPE", "ALRM", "TERM", "URG", "STOP", "TSTP", "CONT", "CHLD", "TTIN", "TTOU", "IO", "XCPU", "XFSZ", "VTALRM", "PROF", "WINCH", "LOST", "USR1", "USR2", "RTMAX", "CLD", "POLL", "PWR", "RTMIN", 0'
sig_num='0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 20 23 29 32 '
sig_num_init='0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 20, 23, 29, 32, 0'
```

(I copied these values from a `config.sh` from a build for a newer version of Perl. The values you need may vary slightly)

Comment: Isn't #1, path has no spaces.

Comment: #2 didn't work unfortunately. I edited config.sh in the bld directory, make clean, make, make install and the build still fails. perl.exe core dumps just like before.

Comment: My client really wants this old release of Perl to work. Can you help me understand what